# One Fragment with multi inner fragments for many tabs

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-framelayout

I want a tab layout in which, **on every tab there are two fragments, One above showing a progress of a task** that is completed by giving input in 3 tabs, from start to end, **and another main fragment below that progress fragment** that will be taking input.

**That makes a title and detail in every tab**, title fragment same and detail fragment (input fragment different on each tab)!

I tried all methods for two days :(

**My Solution**
i tried a layout that contains two framelayout for main fragment that is added into two tabs from ViewPager,showed here:

```
public static class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends
        FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public static ArrayList<Fragment> tabs_fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>(
            3);

    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm,
            ArrayList<Fragment> tabs) {
        super(fm);
        ScreenSlidePagerAdapter.tabs_fragments = tabs;

    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
        return tabs_fragments.get(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tabs_fragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        if (tabs_fragments.contains(object)) {
            return POSITION_UNCHANGED;
        }
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    public static void setItem(Fragment fr, int position) {
        if (position <= 2 && position >= 0) {
            tabs_fragments.remove(position);
            tabs_fragments.add(position, fr);
        } else
            Log.d("adding tab", "wrong tab position to add fragment at");
    }
}
```

On activity start i do this, see i get tab position that is used in main fragment for loading detail fragment for different tab positions:

```
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    // fragments for pagers
    ArrayList<Fragment> tabs = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
    tabs.add(new FrEventDetails());
    tabs.add(new FrEventDetails());
    tabs.add(new FrRuleSave());
    mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getFragmentManager(), tabs);
    mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

    bar = getActionBar();
    bar.setTitle("Add Rule");
    bar.setSubtitle("select event for rule");
    bar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    bar.setDisplayOptions(0, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
    bar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    bar.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Select Event")
            .setTabListener(new TabListener(mPager)));
    bar.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Select Action")
            .setTabListener(new TabListener(mPager)));
    bar.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Save Rule")
            .setTabListener(new TabListener(mPager)));

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        bar.setSelectedNavigationItem(savedInstanceState.getInt("tab", 0));
    }
    mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // When swiping between pages, select the
            // corresponding tab.
            if (bar.getSelectedNavigationIndex() != position)
                bar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            tab = position;
        }
```

and then when this fragment is attaching to activity I add a progress layout (title( for one frame-layout and based on the selected tab, add another fragment for detail frame layout(for input). 
showed here:

```
public class FrEventDetails extends Fragment {
Context context;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    context = (Context) activity;
    int tab = AddRule1.tab;
    android.app.FragmentTransaction ft = activity.getFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction();
     ft.add(R.id.fr_rule_progress_container, new FrProgress());

    if (tab == 1) {
        ft.replace(R.id.fr_event_input_container, new FrActionSelect(),
                "cell1_1").commit();
    } else if (tab == 0) {
        ft.replace(R.id.fr_event_action_container, new FrEventSelect(),
                "cell1_2").commit();
    }

}
```

**NOTE*** layout for this main fragment is simple containing two framelayouts.

**result :**  It shows on start a title and detail beautifully on first tab, but on second tab, only main fragment and,
  when i swipe to third fragment and come back, second fragment is filled beautifully (after 1 second of showing) but 1st fragment is now empty.
 i can't understand what to do with this. 
please give some solution to this tearful problem of two days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To Show all Tabs at the same time in start, increase PagerOffSetLimit (to 2 in this case for 3 tabs)
2. For refreshing state of fragment or calling some methods on your fragment in the tab beside your current tab, use the Pager.instantiateItem method.

   1. One second delay is because you have on the animateLayoutChanges in your xml.